# Is there a transformation to solve $\int_{0}^{v}(v-x)^2\delta_1(x)dx - \int_{0}^{v}(v-x)^2\delta_0(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

If we have the following integral containing Dirac delta functions:

$\int_{0}^{v}(v-x)^2\delta_1(x)dx  - \int_{0}^{v}(v-x)^2\delta_0(x)dx$,

where $\delta_1(x)$ evaluates to 1 if $x=1$ and $\delta_0(x)$ evaluates to 1 if $x=0$.

Is there a (linear) transformation such that we can transform the integral domain from $(0,v)$ to $(-a,a)$. Or is there another way to solve this integral?

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

What I tried:
By symmetry:

$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-v}^{v} (v-x)^2\delta_1(x)dx - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-v}^{v} (v-x)^2\delta_0(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}(v-1)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(v-0)^2 = \frac{1}{2} - v$.

However, I was told that symmetry is not the way due to the Dirac function.

And how can we then solve the following: I got $a(u)=1-2u$, however the textbook says $a(u)=-u$

$a(u) = \iint_{\hat{v}<v}(v-\hat{v})^2F(u,v) \frac{\partial}{\partial u} F(u,\hat{v}) d\hat{v} dv$ where $F(u,v) = (1-u)\delta_0(v)+u\delta_1(v)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} F(u, \hat{v}) = -\delta_0(\hat{v})+\delta_1(\hat{v})$

Comment: What have you tried ? Why do you need such a transformation (instead of evaluating the integrals straightforwardly).

Comment: I have included what I did. But I was told that this way is not helpful and that I should consider a linear transformation.

Comment: The way you discuss these Dirac deltas indicates a misunderstanding. They do not evaluate to 1, they evaluate to infinity. They integrate to 1

Comment: Are you able to show me what that looks like? I am not quit sure how to continue from that

Comment: $\int_{a}^b f(x) \delta(x-c) dx = f(c)\Theta(b-c)\Theta(c-a) $. This is the sifting property of the Dirac delta. Note that $\Theta(0)=1/2$. If you want, you can always use $\delta_1(x)=\delta(x-1)$ and subsitute $x' = x-1$ into the integral.

Comment: Thankyou! This helps me a lot! I have edited the question with an additional integral. However, I am not able to get the right answer with the use of your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry doesn't really help in that case. Let's recall the "definition" of the Dirac delta :
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,\delta_c(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
   f(c)            & \mathrm{if}\; c \in (a,b) \\
   \frac{1}{2}f(c) & \mathrm{if}\; c=a \;\mathrm{or}\; c=b \\
   0               & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Note that the middle line is a "limit case", whose convention can differ among references. In consequence, the first integral evaluates as
$$
\int_0^v (v-x)^2\delta_1(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
   (v-1)^2 & \mathrm{if}\; v > 1 \\
   0   & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
while the second one gives
$$
\int_0^v (v-x)^2\delta_0(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
   v^2 & \mathrm{if}\; v > 0 \\
   0   & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Your answer assumes v exceeds 1

Comment: @kevinkayaks  That's now corrected.

Comment: Thankyou very much! This part is clear for me. However, I edited the question with an additional question which I still can't answer or at least I got the wrong answer. Can you maybe explain the following up integral for me?